# Why is my router animation in Angular 8 not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

So I have used [this](https://medium.com/@tejozarkar/angular-route-transition-animation-in-5-easy-steps-ab0ddc8230e) tutorial as a guide to get my routes animated. I am not getting any errors but it simply would not animate and I cannot figure out what I have missed. I'm sure it must be something very small! Looking forward to your input.

this `body.component.html`, this is where my `router-outlet` is supposed to be, there in its `.ts` file i have also imported my animation configurations as such `import { slideInAnimation } from '../route-animation';`

```html
<section [@routeAnimations]="o && o.activatedRouteData
      && o.activatedRouteData['animation']" class="app-body" [class.nav--open]="menu.isMenuClosed">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</section>
```

Below my `route-animation.ts`

```js
import {
    transition,
    trigger,
    query,
    style,
    animate,
    group,
    animateChild
} from '@angular/animations';


export const slideInAnimation =
    trigger('routeAnimations', [
        transition('* => *', [
            query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
            group([
                query(':enter', [
                    style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
                    animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
                ], { optional: true }),
                query(':leave', [
                    style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
                    animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
                ], { optional: true }),
            ])
        ]),
    ]);
```

Finally my `app-routing.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutSectionComponent } from './body/about-section/about-section.component';
import { ToursSectionComponent } from './body/tours-section/tours-section.component';
import { GallerySectionComponent } from './body/gallery-section/gallery-section.component';
import { ContactSectionComponent } from './body/contact-section/contact-section.component';
import { IndexSectionComponent } from './body/index-section/index-section.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexSectionComponent},
  { path: 'about', component: AboutSectionComponent, data: {animation: 'About'}},
  { path: 'tours', component: ToursSectionComponent, data: {animation: 'Tours'}},
  { path: 'gallery', component: GallerySectionComponent, data: {animation: 'Gallery'}},
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactSectionComponent, data: {animation: 'Contact'}},
  { path: 'index', component: IndexSectionComponent, data: {animation: 'Index'}}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: If you temporarily remove the option "optional" or set it to false, it might uncover what is causing the problem. Though the issue is not with this setting, it might not be finding your elements like you expect it to

Comment: Are you including in the main module the BrowserAnimationsModule?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Yes I have imported the BrowserAnimationsModule in the main module!

Comment: It seems there is some problem in my animations file, so I have copied this https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8